# How to return a 3rd column, after looking up 2 columns in a df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, I have a df like so:

```
df2
ColA   ColB   ColC
 A       1     Bob
 A       2     Cat
 B       3     Hi
```

Say Im using a loop on another df1, and I have Val1 = 'A', and Val2 = '1' in my current iteration.
And I want to get 'Bob' returned, and use it in df1.

It is sort of like vlookup, but with 2 columns as the lookup.

I know I can have an entire df2 returned, but I only wish to get the value from ColC, on the condition that the ColA, and ColB match the values that Im am feeding it like so:

```
df.loc[(df2['ColA'] == 'A') & (df2['ColB'] == '1')]
```

But again, I just want the single value returned from ColC :|

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to change this dataframe by setting an index from `ColA` and `ColB`:

```py
df = df.set_index(["ColA", "ColB"])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
          ColC
ColA ColB     
A    1     Bob
     2     Cat
B    3      Hi
```

Then to find `ColC` value `('A', 1)` you can do:

```py
print(df.loc[("A", 1), "ColC"])
```

Prints:

```
Bob
```

---

Another possible option is to merge values from `df2` to `df1` - but it depends on your use case.

Comment: Thanks Andrej, but what happens if I then need to look up a value that was "A", "2", and want to get "Cat" back?  (Only asking cause it looks like the second A in the second rows went away in your post.

Comment: @BeeLiBaaLa `df.loc[("A", 2), "ColC"]` will bring "Cat". The "missing" value in `ColA` is just how pandas prints the multi-index dataframe. But maybe you want to merge values from df2 to df1 and not use `.loc`

Answer (score 0):

One option:

```
Val1 = 'A'
Val2 = '1'

out = next(iter(df.loc[df['ColA'].eq(Val1) & df['ColB'].eq(Val2), 'ColC']), None)
```

Or, if you are sure that there is a single match:

```
out = df.loc[df['ColA'].eq(Val1) & df['ColB'].eq(Val2), 'ColC'].squeeze()
```

Or:

```
out = df.merge(pd.DataFrame([(Val1, Val2)], columns=['ColA', 'ColB'])
               )['ColC'].squeeze()
```

Output: `'Bob'`